# PHP: mysqli extension doesn't load

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

I try to use MySQL with PHP and I have this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in 'file_name Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 'file_name'`

When doing `print_r( get_defined_functions())`, I see that the MySQLi extension isn't there, but it is "loaded" in the `php.ini` file (I mean this is not in a commentary).

I specify that the PHP directory is in the PATH (I'm under windows) and MySQL, PHP and Apache are on my C: disk.

I don't know where is the problem, this is probably a small thing but I can't see which one so.

My versions are:

```
Apache 2.4.47
PHP 7.1.7
MySQL 5.7
Windows 7
```

PS : `php_mysqli.dll` do only 97k. I don't know if it's normal.

HOW I SOLVED THIS : I have just added `extension_dir="path_to_php\ext"` under the lines who load extentions, in the php.ini file. This line is used to indicate where are the extentions in your hard disk. Don't forget to restart your server, it will reload the php.ini file.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the correct `php.ini` file? There's usually a different one for CLI and webserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, run `phpinfo()` to make sure you are looking at the correct `php.ini`.

If your `php.ini` file has `extension=php_mysqli.dll` uncommented check your extension directory. You may need to set it explicitly, like:

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

If the problem persists check the apache error log, you should find more info there.

Comment: phpinfo() display the same version of PHP, and I have tried to add the directory of php_mysqli.dll manually, in differents ways, but nothing worked, and the apache log say only the same thing as my project : Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Comment: It's not the php version you have to look in phpinfo() data, it's the location of the php.ini file which is using your web server. Check that you are looking at the correct file.

Comment: I have searched this too, and this is the good file which is loaded. There is also a mention to "c:/Windows" but after a few try, it don't change anything

Comment: Have you restarted the apache web server every time you edit something in the php.ini file? If you don't restart it it won't load the changes.

Comment: Well... It was that, I have added `extension_dir="path_to_php\ext"`under the lines who loads modules and after restarting the server, it works